# Redundant typing in writing simple function type

Tags: typescript

Looking at the docs regarding Typescript, they show an [example of writing the function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type).

```
let myAdd: (x: number, y: number) => number =
    function(x: number, y: number): number { return x + y; };
```

It took me a while to decipher the above and when I finally did, it seemed like redundant typing.

Doesn't `myAdd` automatically get the typing defined from the right side of the expression? I don't see the point of basically defining it again (in a slightly different format) on the left.

What am I still not understanding?

Comment: I think it’s only for pedagogic matters. If you look at the [next paragraph](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#inferring-the-types), they say that TypeScript infers the function type. So you can indeed avoid this syntax (from my experience, everybody does).

Comment: Ah right! So I'm still confused as to what syntax is the preferred or accepted way? (i.e. type left or right side)

Comment: Whatever you and your team prefer/accept is the preferred/accepted way. Both are syntactically correct. My team generally only adds types on the left side in cases where inference does not work.

Comment: I guess it’s a matter of preference, but frankly, I would go for the shorter version, i.e. type once on the function definition. It’s more readable, and more closely matches the syntax of strongly-typed languages.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the section immediately following, ["Inferring the types"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#inferring-the-types)?

> In playing with the example, you may notice that the TypeScript compiler can figure out the type even if you only have types on one side of the equation:
>
> ```
> // myAdd has the full function type
> let myAdd = function(x: number, y: number):
>     number { return x + y; };
> ```